# Will getting high chaos on the first level result in a bad ending?

Tags: dishonored

I don't want to do low chaos and get the bad ending again (this is my second time running through the game).

I got high chaos on the first level.  Will that make me have a bad ending?

Comment: Okay, but what are you actually wanting help/advice on?

Comment: Oops I forgot I had trouble posting it deleted it

Comment: I'm sooo glad someone actually read my question!

Answer (score 2):

No, getting a high Chaos rating on the first mission alone will not make you get the high chaos ending (which I assume is what you meant by "bad"). It seems like you need to consistently get high Chaos ratings the entire game to receive the "bad ending."

For instance, a user in [this thread](http://steamcommunity.com/app/205100/discussions/0/828925849248206914/) states that he got a high Chaos rating on the second level, but didn't get the bad ending:

> I got a high chaos rate on the second mission and killed around 15 on the others missions together. I still got the good ending

According to the [wiki](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Chaos), in order to receive the "bad ending", you must have killed at least 50% of all encountered Dunwall citizens:

> If Corvo's total kills exceed 50% of the population seen in Dishonored, Dunwall is irrevocably thrown into chaos, and the high chaos ending is depicted.

Comment: Oh I'm almost not killing any second time I'm on second level.do I have to kill the pendalton twins? Does slack jaw help with no Lethal?

Comment: And thanks soooo much guys i just didn't want 2 play th game over and get that high chaos ending....thank you!

Comment: @Sman if this answered your question, make sure to mark it as accepted in case anyone else has the same question in the future